# Spyne. How can i make service for one tag xml

Tags: python, django, rpc, xml-rpc, spyne

Worked on python 2.7, django 1.6, spyne 2.11

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE inquiry_A2 SYSTEM "inquiry_A2.dtd">
<!-- Optional -->
<inquiry_A2>
    <!-- Optional -->
    <Consignee>
        <AgencyCode>123123</AgencyCode>
        <PartyID>123123</PartyID>
    </Consignee>
    <SubstitutionIndicator>123123</SubstitutionIndicator>
    <Campaign>123123</Campaign>
    <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
</inquiry_A2>
```

inquiry_A2 is a root element
I want to make spyne proceed this request, but i can't figure out how to make this?
The problem is that spyne rpc need both method name and param, for example:

```
@rpc(RequestInquiry)
def inquiry_A2(ctx, inquiry_A2):
    return True
```

But with this example spyne generated xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE inquiry_A2 SYSTEM "inquiry_A2.dtd">
<!-- Optional -->
<inquiry_A2>
    <inquiry_A2>
        <!-- Optional -->
        <Consignee>
            <AgencyCode>123123</AgencyCode>
            <PartyID>123123</PartyID>
        </Consignee>
        <SubstitutionIndicator>123123</SubstitutionIndicator>
        <Campaign>123123</Campaign>
        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
    </inquiry_A2>
</inquiry_A2>
```

Is that possibile to do with spyne? I can't change incoming xml

Comment: does passing `_body_style='bare'` to @rpc solve your issue?

Comment: @BurakArslan thanks a lot, i tried _body_style='bare' and its help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
@rpc(RequestInquiry, _body_style='bare')
def inquiry_A2(ctx, inquiry_A2):
    return True
```